# Keep root directory htaccess from redirecting subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a *root domain* that I removed the `.php` extension, which is now interfering with my *subdomain Wordpress platform*. I can't post any content because the root domain `.htaccess` is *redirecting* `.php` to no extension so I keep getting `HTTP 404 Error`. How can I apply the the hide extension only to the *root* and not the *subdomain*? Here is what I have in the *root*:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I set up multiple websites on the same computer, I point them to different directories. This keeps .htaccess (and everything else) separate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a `RewriteCond` that checks `%{HTTP_HOST}` for a subdomain. Something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]` should only apply a rule if the domain starts with `www.`. You can see a list of rewrite variables on the [mod_rewrite page under RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what AMADANON Inc. said . . . Put an .htaccess in the directory that controls the subdomain. .htaccess is directory specific, so the directory one will overrule the root one as long as you use RewriteBase /directoryname where directoryname is the name of your directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it with MultiView
All you have to do is add this in your .htaccess file

```
# Enable Multiviews
Options +MultiViews
```

Now you can access all files both with siteurl.com/file.php as with siteurl.com/file